# Replacing "," with " "," " in R string

Tags: r, string, replace

I have an R string

```
y <- "age,income,homeowner_status_desc,marital_status_cd,gender,education"
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
y ="age","income","homeowner_status_desc","marital_status_cd","gender","education"
```

So, essentially I want to replace `,` in the string with `","`. I tried using `gsub(",",'","' , y)` but it doesnt give the output I'm looking for.

How can I do it inside R?

Comment: Your `y` doesn't actually have `"` characters in it. Try `cat(y,"\n")` to see what it looks like as plain text.

Comment: Are you just looking to separate the string into parts like: `scan(text=y,sep=",",what=character())` ?

Comment: @hmi2015: Please do notice that the second bit of code is not correct R syntax for assignment, which is the reason people are guessing what you really do want. If you want `y=c( "age", "income", "homeowner_status_desc", "marital_status_cd","gender","education")`, then you should clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just display the output using `cat` function.

```
> y <- "age,income,homeowner_status_desc,marital_status_cd,gender,education"
> gsub(",", "\",\"", y)
[1] "age\",\"income\",\"homeowner_status_desc\",\"marital_status_cd\",\"gender\",\"education"
> x <- gsub(",", "\",\"", y)
> cat(x)
age","income","homeowner_status_desc","marital_status_cd","gender","education
```

Comment: To explain this - you need to escape `"` characters with \

Comment: @hmi2015 - there is no backslash - that's purely in the display in R. Try `cat()` around the above `gsub` answer again to see it in plain text.

Comment: it's the interpreter shows like that. It won't actually has any backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
> (y <- unlist(strsplit(y, ",")))
[1] "age"                   "income"                "homeowner_status_desc" "marital_status_cd"    
[5] "gender"                "education"
```

John